# Hyphen on array key in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to read a property of an array that looks like this:

```
[
    0 => [
        "address" => "0.0.0.0.0"
        "mac-address" => "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
        "server" => "0.0.0.0"
    ]
    1 => [
        "address" => "0.0.0.0"
        "mac-address" => "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
        "server" => "0.0.0.0"
    ]
]
```

If I do

```
echo $the_array[0]['mac-address'];
```

it doesn't work.

I have also tried to convert it into an object and use curly braces to read the property with the dash, but no luck.

I know this is a silly thing but I just can't figure out how to rename that array key to use a more friendly separator like an underscore.

Comment: What error does it gives you

Comment: You attempt should work, _unless_ the characters are not actually the same There are some unicode characters looking similar. For example a hyphen and a dash. Have a try with copy&paste for that character. Or use a hexeditor to examine what character you acutally deal with.

Comment: The dash separator is not a problem. The lack of commas in that array might be

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined index: mac-address

Comment: What's the output if you do `dd($the_array)`?

Comment: Good point arkascha, I'll try it!

Comment: Copy&Paste like arkascha sudgested also throws me an Undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

Please see updated code, it is working, you just miss comma at some places

```
$the_array = [
    0 => [
        "address" => "0.0.0.0.0",
        "mac-address" => "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",
        "server" => "0.0.0.0",
    ],
    1 => [
        "address" => "0.0.0.0",
        "mac-address" => "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",
        "server" => "0.0.0.0",
    ]
];

echo $the_array[0]['mac-address'];
```